# sql to take maximum number from both the tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to query the maximum ID from two tables and I need to take the ID of whichever is larger. i am using sqlserver.

Queries:

```
SELECT MAX(a.ID)
FROM   tableA a

SELECT MAX(b.ID)
FROM   tableB b
```

If `tableA`'s maximum ID is 20 and `tableB`'s maximum ID is 30 then the `UNION` of both the tables query should return only 30.

Is it possible to combine both the queries into a single query to return maximum ID?

Comment: Are you expecting two rows, both of 30? Or one row, of 30?

Answer (score 6):

This is based on what you said, `UNION` both tables and get the maximum value.

```
SELECT max(ID)
FROM
(
    select max(ID) ID from tableA
    UNION
    select max(ID) ID from tableB
) s
```

or

```
SELECT max(ID)
FROM
(
    select ID from tableA
    UNION
    select ID from tableB
) s
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM (SELECT ID FROM tableA
      UNION
      SELECT ID FROM tableB) AS D
```

Answer (score 0):

option without sorting

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN a.ID > b.ID THEN a.ID ELSE b.ID END)
FROM tableA a CROSS JOIN tableB b
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/516d8/1/0)